# How to limit the repositories of a specific module in a multi-module Android project

Tags: android, build.gradle, multi-module

I want to specify specific repositories only for specific modules
I try above code.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

project(':specific_module') {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://specific.repository.url' } -> specific repository
    }
}
```

Sync succeeds, but build fails.

Please help me.
Sorry for may poor english.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share the error logs.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?